# Markdown link to reStructuredText anchor in Sphinx

Tags: python, markdown, anchor, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Is it possible in any way to insert a link to a Markdown file that points to an anchor in a reStructuredText file?

I have a project documentation that contains .rst and .md files as well, and I'm using the [m2rr](https://github.com/qhua948/m2rr) Sphinx extension, however it only seems to support in-file rst anchor links.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Markdown itself does not support cross-referencing to arbitrary locations across documents.

One workaround is to insert an HTML based anchor.

```
[My Label](/root-relative-url.html#anchor-in-page)
```

Another option is to use [MyST](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).  Here you would instead of using markdown for the anchor, you would use either [MyST syntax](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/syntax.html#targets-and-cross-referencing) or embed reST syntax.

> Target headers are defined with this syntax:
>
> ```
> (header_target)=
> ```
>
> They can then be referred to with the ref inline role:
>
> ```
> {ref}`header_target`
> ```
>
> By default, the reference will use the text of the target (such as the section title), but also you can directly specify the text:
>
> ```
> {ref}`my text <header_target>`
> ```

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks. I have created a simple example project for this: https://github.com/waszil/myst-crosslink-example